# How to horizontally center a 2 line text inside a Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I am trying to create a Text widget within a circle. However I am stuck in the part to make the text horizontally centered.

```
Container(
  width: 80,
  height: 80,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.red,
  borderRadius:
    const BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(100.0),
    ),
  ),
  child: const Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Text(
        'Hello\nWorld',
        maxLines: 2,
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

This code splits the text into 2 line, but the text inside is not horizontally centered.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **textAlign: TextAlign.center** to the Text widget.

**Code:**

```
 Text(
    'Hello\nWorld',
     maxLines: 2,
     textAlign: TextAlign.center
 )
```